Youtube API V3 : missing item "Title" in Snippet result of subscriptions
I have a server app to get my "videos to watch" based on my subscriptions on youtube.
I use it since many years but recently (this year, I'm not sure when) I have an error to get the title of channel.
I use this kind of call :
https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet&part=contentDetails&channelId=xxxxx&key=xxxxx
I have not make any change to this call, I never use OAUTH.
When I try with the developer API explorer :
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list?hl=fr&apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22snippet%22%2C%22contentDetails%22%5D%2C%22channelId%22%3A%xxxxxx%22%7D#usage
And it's clear : when I check OAUTH credential, I have this :
        "publishedAt": "2024-04-14T11:58:45.218188Z",
        "title": "Len et Jerry",
        "description" .... 

When I uncheck OAUTH and keep APIKEY :
        "publishedAt": "2017-04-09T08:38:00Z",
        "description"

I don't understand :

Why I don't get the title when use only API KEY (but other item remain present)
Why there is a change on the API V3

I don't want to use OAUTH, lot of work to use it properly on server side and I don't want to make a change if the problem on api side is temporary but I don't find anything on API changelog about this.

Are you using any code to read the response?- it might be a bug. If so, consider post your issue on Issue Tracker.

I've tested on the Explorer API and it does bring the title. See this test - see my response sample here

Thank you.
Yeah, I have code to read the response, but to avoid any problem with code, I get the raw json data to check for title
On your test, it's seem that you use OAUT

Thank you again for the issue tracker
I search and found this one and seems to be the same problem :
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/346918503
